# Selective 302 redirect

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-302

I am making cURL calls from php scripts on one domain (mac2cash.com) to another (thebookyard.com), both hosted on the same Apache server and the same IP address. This has been working fine but I need to add some new functionality to the site and I have just created a new php script at the root level of the same target domain as the cURL call that is working, but when I call this new script using the same code I used on the working script, this is returning the message "Found: the document has moved here".

The target scripts for the working and failing cURL calls are at the root level of the same domain. I have checked they have the same unix permissions. But if I simply change the php file name in the working script to the name of the target script in the failing call, this now fails too with the same 302 redirect message. 
I even duplicated the 'working' target script (byasd_api.php) on the target domain to a new file (byasd_api_copy.php) and I get the 302 message if I make a cURL call to that from the calling script that was working even though the code is exactly the same!
I cannot see what the difference is between the two files. Is there some kind of cacheing going on where newly created files are not being treated the same?

For reference, here is the calling code:

```
    $header=array("Host:thebookyard.com"); 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, HTTP_SERVER_IP."/byasd_api.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.mac2cash.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);            
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

The 'byasd_api.php' script name is the only thing I am changing.

I've spent some hours googling for a solution so would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason for the difference in behaviour was that the working script name was included as a rewrite condition in the htaccess file which was redirecting http to https. Changing the CURL url to "https://".HTTP_SERVER_IP."/byasd_api.php" stopped the "Found: the document has moved here" error but the call was then failing because CURL was trying to validate the SSL certificate for the IP address rather than the domain. 
The solution to that was to add the following : 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, array("www.thebookyard.com:443:".HTTP_SERVER_IP,));
This still allows the call to be to the IP address (which is much faster than via the domain name) but CURL validates the SSL certificate against the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache have configurated to search favicon.ico in each call the 302 is because not find the ico

GET http://theboo....com/favicon.ico   [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 151ms]

Change the cofiguration or add the favicon.ico file.

Maybe the configuration try to find the ico file only in the root

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where are you seeing this? I get no such messages in Safari console. Also, would this explain why one script works but another script in the same location on the same site does not?